# Errors in model namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I broke up my signup into an overall Signup model with multiple model namespaces (I believe these are what they are called) into separate files.  For example,

Signup.rb

```
class ContractorSignup < ActiveRecord::Base
# It has fields of first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, address
end
```

In the signup folder there are these models

```
ContractorSignup::Personal < Signup
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number
end
```

In the form I am using the main model

```
= form_for @contractor_signup, url: signup_step_path('email') do |form|
= form.label :first_name
= form.text_field :first_name
= form.submit "Next"
```

The form comes back responding to the correct validation but I cannot figure out how to grab the errors that it captures based on the validation.

This next is for a Rails wizard built duplicating this person's talk.  http://www.codepainter.ca/2013/10/ultra-light-maintainable-wizards-in.html

If I do a `@contractor_signup.errors.inspect` I see no messages in `@contractor_signup.errors.inspect` when I am filling in a completely blank form.  However, I found that if I submit a form with everything but first name, or last name filled out I receive a message in errors saying `first_name []`

Comment: How about `@contractor_signup.errors[:first_name]`?

Comment: Have you tried `@contractor_signup.errors.full_messages`? It should return an array of error messages encountered in your validation.